# Masonry on iphone ignores percentage-based margins

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, ios

No bottom margins are present when using Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com) on iOS when set with percentages. Changing margins to pixels fixes the problem. Triggering layout after the fact also works. Any suggested fixes for this?

```
<style type="text/css">
  .item { margin-bottom:5% }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">    
$(function(){
  var $container = $('.masonry');

  $container.masonry({
    columnWidth: 60,
    gutter: 10
  });

});
</script>
```

See example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5PNpt/

Answer (score 0):

assuming you want the margin-bottom to be 5% of the height, you can run a jQuery to set the margin-bottom value as pixel by multiplying 5% x height